# Pronunciation of words that rhyme with "bare"

Tags: pronunciation, american-english

I listened to the pronunciation of words containing *ar* with the *Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary* I have on my computer; in particular, I checked the pronunciation of the following words:

- Dare
- Care
- Mare
- Bear
- Bare

I noticed that the pronunciation, for example, of *bare* is reported as /ber/, but the word seems to be pronounced as /be<sup>ə</sup>r/. (I hope it's clear what I mean.)

Is that exact, or am I misunderstanding the pronunciation of those words?

Strangely, the pronunciation in British English of those words is shown as containing the /eə/ sound, but I perceive a single sound (maybe prolonged).

Comment: This is one of the parts of English phonology which varies most widely between dialects - especially the terminal, which 'rhotic' dialects realize as a lateral consonant and 'non-rhotic' dialects mostly as a glide onto /ə/--except in certain phonetic contexts, where it may be realized as a tip-r with no preceding glide.

Comment: In British English pronunciation, it's definitely the diphthong that you show.

Comment: The pronunciation of these varies radically in different dialects. I assume you're talking about the American pronunciation. It can be either /beɚ/ or /ber/, which I think are the two alternatives you're asking about. I use both (!), depending on whether the following sound is a consonant or a vowel.

Comment: At least where I'm from in America those words all rhyme perfectly.

Comment: @PeterShor I am talking of the pronunciation in American English, and the difference between the reported pronunciation, and the pronunciation I hear.

Comment: I may not have been clear in my comment; I believe the pronunciation varies between the two possibilities you mention over different American dialects. I assume your hearing is correct.

Comment: @PeterShor But it should not be shown the pronunciation used by an American dialect, and have an audio file that shows the pronunciation of another American dialect.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: it probably shouldn't. But for many Americans, like me, *bear* and *berry* have the same phoneme but are pronounced differently (/beɚ/ and /beri/). In fact, *bear* is pronounced differently depending on what phoneme the word after starts with (/beɚ/ for most consonants and at the end of a phrase, and /ber/ for vowels). This is too complicated for a learner's dictionary to deal with.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: On the other hand, the OALD gives /mæri/ for the pronunciation of *marry*, but to me the audio definitely sounds like /meri/ (although they pronounce *parry* with an /æ/). So they don't match the dialect with their pronunciation.

Comment: @PeterShor May you write an answer with what you write in your comments? I think they answer my question.

Comment: when I was at school the pronunciation of our was always ar never owrs since when has tbis changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pronunciation of *bare* (and similar words) in American English varies between different AmE dialects. For Americans who don't drop their r's, it is either [ber] or [be<sup>ə</sup>r]; most Americans have the *merry/Mary* merger and treat these as the same phoneme. For some Americans (like me) this phoneme is pronounced /er/ before a vowel and /e<sup>ə</sup>r/ before a consonant or a pause. So I would say [ker ʌv] (*care of*) and [ke<sup>ə</sup>r fɔr] (*care for*). For many Americans, the same holds for the phonemes in *are, air, ear, oar, tour*.

The OALD really has to choose one notation for this phoneme, even though it gets pronounced different ways; otherwise it would make learning English even more confusing than it needs to be. On the other hand, the OALD doesn't always manage to make the audio pronunciation match the written pronunciation: it gives /mæri/ for the pronunciation of *marry,* but to me the audio definitely sounds like /meri/; these two different pronunciations are both correct, but depend on the dialect of the speaker.

Answer (score -1):

It is pronounced as *air* in these instances; it is pronounced as *our* or *are* in the case of *car*, *hard*, *bar*, *star* etc.

Comment: -1, as I say "our" and "are" _very_ differently.